# jquery doesn't work with jsdom/enzyme

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, enzyme, jsdom

I have a minimum test react app with following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount', $('#helloDiv').length);
    }

    render() {
        return <div id='helloDiv'>
            Hello React!
                </div>;
    }
}
```

this works fine when loading it in browser (Chrome). The console.log() in componentDidMount() prints out 1 helloDiv element found

However, if I run the test using mocha + enzyme + jsdom, the same console.log() in App component prints out 0:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import App from '../src/client/app/first'

describe('first test', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {        
        const app = mount(<App />);
        expect(app.find('#helloDiv').length).to.eq(1);
    });
});
```

**Note: I don't have problem with this unit test, it's passing. The real problem is when < App /> is mounted using enzyme, componentDidMount() is called but the console.log() statement inside it prints out 0, instead of 1**

Here is how I run mocha:

```
mocha --require enzyme/withDom --compilers js:babel-core/register test/index.test.js
```

Any idea why jquery selector doesn't find anything in the test? It should not be mocha issue because the same issue happens if I change to jest

Comment: Consider using `cheerio` for Node.Js applications instead of jQuery.

Comment: @Mijago thanks for the suggestion. However in my case I don't have much choice, at least for the moment. This is a simplified version of current project that I'm working on and jquery has been used throughout the project

Comment: Maybe `app.find('#helloDiv')` searches **inside** of app, but app itself has the id? Your jQuery version searches the whole document.

Comment: @Prinzhorn sorry, I think my test is a bit misleading. I don't have problem with the expect itself. The problem is when mounting <App /> component, componentDidMount() is called, but the console.log() inside it prints out 0. I'll update the question to clarify this

Comment: I guess the answer still applies. The component is not actually mounted inside any document where jQuery could find it. It only exists inside the enzyme ReactWrapper?

Comment: @Prinzhorn correct me if I'm wrong: as I understand, enzyme will use jsdom as headless browser and mount (fully render) this react component inside jsdom document. In that case jquery is going to work with jsdom document and should be able to find the helloDiv?

Comment: If you're using React, don't also use jQuery. React lets you program with the *explicit promise* that the fact that there's a DOM is irrelevant. Everything you need to do, you do without needing to touch the DOM; that's React's "under the hood" work. If you need to know how many children are contained by a component: you *know* how many, because you wrote the code that generated those children as part of the `render()` function. Using jQuery to find information by inspecting the DOM makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found the issue:

Enzyme `mount(<SomeComponent />)` by default will do full DOM rendering but not insert the rendered component into current document (JSDom). That's why jQuery cannot find any element in current document

To do full DOM rendering AND attach to current document:

```
mount(<SomeComponent />, { attachTo: document.getElementById('app') });
```

Where `app` is empty div available when jsdom is setup:

```
global.document = jsdom('<html><head></head><body><div id="app" /></body></html>');
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. Your answer partially resolve it. But the problem is that I am running my test cases by `npm run test -- --watch`  where `test` is `mocha --require babel-polyfill --require babel-core/register --require ./test/withDom.js --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test` command to run test cases. So, in first run everything runs fine but as soon as i modify some test cases and the watcher re runs the test cases automatically and the issue you mentioned appears again. I will be very grateful if you resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be some setup done before you could jsdom with jquery in node-env.

Try this if it helps.

Create a test helper file like this -

**test_helper.js**

```
import _$ from 'jquery';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiJquery from 'chai-jquery';

global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
global.window = global.document.defaultView;
global.navigator = global.window.navigator;
const $ = _$(window);

chaiJquery(chai, chai.util, $);

export {expect};
```

While running -

```
mocha --require enzyme/withDom --compilers js:babel-core/register --require test/test_helper.js test/index.test.js
```

or another way use jsdom-global without test_helper.js file.

```
npm install --save-dev jsdom-global
```

Then :

```
import 'jsdom-global/register'; 

//at the top of file , even  , before importing react
```

Comment: no, I don't get any error. the output of console.log() is still 0. I guess if it's jquery issue, it will complain about $ not found etc

Comment: is your test_helper file being used from the directory you have provided?
put some console.log in test_helper.js file to see if it is referenced correctly

Comment: sorry for late reply. I have found the issue. See my answer for more details

Comment: Issue was certainly related to jsdom.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get [Phuong Nguyen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42218937/2299084) to work. I did find [the relevant page in the enzyme docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/detach.html). I ended up with something like, based on the final example on that page:

```
const div = global.document.createElement('div');
global.document.body.appendChild(graphDiv);
const wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent />, { attachTo: div });  // same as the other answer
// clean up after ourselves
wrapper.detach();
global.document.body.removeChild(div);
```

Comment: It seems that `graphDiv` is not defined. Maybe `graphDiv` should be replaced with `div`. Is it right?