# jest fails on third party function called on jquery selector

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jestjs

I have a react component that calls `dataTable()` function of `datatables.js` on `jQuery` selector. I also have corresponding jest test component for the component but, tests fail on the function throwing the following error.

`● components › <Page /> › check props matchs`
`TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).dataTable is not a function`

**Page.js** react component

```js
import 'datatables.net-se'

class Page extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    $('.table').dataTable()
  }
 }
```

**Page.test.js** jest component (Test fails in the **it** block)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { configure, shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import 'datatables.net-se'
jest.mock('datatables.net-se', () => ({ dataTable: jest.fn() }))

// Components 
import Page from '../../components/Customers/Page'

// Setups
const middlewares = [thunk] // add your middlewares like `redux-thunk`
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

let store, props, component, wrapper

describe("<Page />", function() {  

  beforeEach(()=>{
    const storeStateMock = {
      customers: Customers
    }

    store = mockStore(storeStateMock)

    props = {
      fetchCustomers: jest.fn()
    }

    wrapper = mount(<BrowserRouter><Provider store={store}><Page {...props} /></Provider></BrowserRouter>)
  })

  it('renders connected component', function() { 

    expect(wrapper.find(Page).length).toEqual(1)
  })

})

}
```

Answer (score 5):

After trying various alternatives I've got tests passed by attaching `dataTable` function to `jQuery` as shown below. On the application side this doesn't make any difference; I could import `dataTable` as `import 'datatables.net-se'` or `$.fn.dataTable = require('datatables.net')` and it still works in both cases.

**Page** component

```
$.fn.dataTable = require('datatables.net')

class Page extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {    
    $('.table').dataTable()
  }
 }
```

Comment: When using the solution I got past the error DataTables is not a function but I am not running into the issue `table.buttons()` is not a function. Did you also run into that?

Comment: @DanielButler Don't quite remember it, since it's been a while since I had faced this error. But, I assume my problems then was solved by the solution I've put here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you still need to attach the mounted component to the jsdom environment so that jquery is able to find it. See [jquery doesn't work with jsdom/enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161238/jquery-doesnt-work-with-jsdom-enzyme#answer-42218937)

Comment: jQuery was found by jest and tests of other Components with jQuery or with out it passes. The problem is that jest can't find other third-party function that needs to be attached to jquery selector function. I have some tweak that seems to solve this issue and I will answer here as well. However, am still not sure if this is the right way of solving it.

Comment: @bir_ham: I am going through the same issue, how did you resolve this then?