# Testing in JSDOM: Jquery not finding the elements in Enzyme Mocha on successive runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme, jsdom

I am running my test cases by `npm run test -- --watch` where `test` is `mocha --require babel-polyfill --require babel-core/register --require ./test/withDom.js --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test` command to run test cases using `mocha`.

My components uses `Jquery` actively to manipulate DOM and handle the events.

In my first run all the test cases runs fine. But as soon as I modify some test cases and the watcher re-runs the test cases automatically; the `jquery` is not able to find the dom elements using selectors hereafter. This is evident because page `DOM` is not modified when I console log the `wrapper.html()` or `body.innerHTML`.

I will be very grateful if any of you resolve this.

Here is the code

**withDom.js**

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  Object.defineProperties(target, {
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(src),
    ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(target),
  });
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};
global.requestAnimationFrame = function (callback) {
  return setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
global.cancelAnimationFrame = function (id) {
  clearTimeout(id);
};
copyProps(window, global);
```

**test_helper.js**

```
import _$ from 'jquery';
import { mount, render, shallow, configure} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../src/reducers';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
global.expect = expect;
global.mount = mount;
global.render = render;
global.shallow = shallow;
const $ = _$(window);

function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props = {}, state = {}) {
  const componentInstance =  ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Provider store = {createStore(reducers, state)}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <ComponentClass {...props} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
  console.log('helper',componentInstance);
  return $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(componentInstance));
}
export {renderComponent};
```

**example_test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { MemoryRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import ItemList from '../../src/components/ItemList';
import RandomRater from '../../src/containers/RandomRater';
import { loadBooks } from '../../src/actions/index';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
let store, books, wrapper, params;

describe('<RandomRater/> Component',() => {

    beforeEach(()=>{
        store = mockStore();
        store.dispatch(loadBooks());
        books = store.getActions()[0].payload;
        params = { 'params': {'title' : 'Html & CSS Design & Build website' } };
    });

    it('renders <RandomRater/> containing <ItemList/> and <Link/>',()=>{     
        wrapper = mount(
                    <MemoryRouter>
                        <RandomRater store={store} books={books} match={params} />
                    </MemoryRouter>,
                    { attachTo: document.getElementById('root') }
                    );
        expect(wrapper).to.exist;
        expect(wrapper.contains(ItemList)).to.equal(true);
        expect(wrapper.contains(Link)).to.equal(true);
        expect(wrapper.text()).to.contains('Start Random Rating');
        expect(wrapper.text()).to.contains('Back');
    });

    it('<RandomRater/> random rates the books',()=>{
        //Below line is not modifying the dom after the first run. 
        wrapper.find('#btn-random-rate').simulate('click',{button:0});
        console.log('body',document.body.innerHTML);

        //This functions only runs on first run and not after that.
        setTimeout(()=>{
             expect(wrapper.text()).to.contains('Stop Random Rating')   
        },200);
        wrapper.detach();    
    });

    after(()=>{
       wrapper.detach(); 
    });
});
```

**Note:**

If I run the given `mocha` command manually each time the issue does not occur. It only occurs when I run with `--watch`.

I have referred following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161238/jquery-doesnt-work-with-jsdom-enzyme) but the my issue remain unresolved.

**Update:**

Here is the [github repo](https://github.com/muhammed-salman/items-random-rater/) with complete code. You can modify the test cases for `RandomRater` (see given RandomRater test file here) and `Rater` to reproduce the problem. (See `DOM` after the simulating click event at the `Start Rating` button for `RandomRater` and similarly for stars in `Rater`)